# Trying to upload an image from android app to cloud using kinvey

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kinvey, cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an image, saved in the internal memory of my phone, clicked by an android app to a cloud service, and am using Kinvey to do so. But I'm facing some problems with it.

Every time I run the code that contains the upload part, I encounter an exception. I'm uploading an image of ".png" type. Any conversion to blob is not a necessary process that is required, unlike that in Google Cloud Platform.

Here is my .java code -

```
`Client mKinveyClient = new Client.Builder(APP_KEY, SECRET_KEY, this.getApplicationContext()).build();
    mKinveyClient.enableDebugLogging();

    mKinveyClient.ping(new KinveyPingCallback() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Kinvey Ping Failed", t);
        }
        public void onSuccess(Boolean b) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Kinvey Ping Success");
        }
    });

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Camera/" + "IMG_20161115_193353.jpg");

    mKinveyClient.file().upload(file, new UploaderProgressListener() {
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "successfully upload file");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileMetaData fileMetaData) { 
                Log.i(TAG, "successfully uploaded file");
            }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to upload file.", error);
            }
        @Override
        public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
            Log.i(TAG, "upload progress: " + uploader.getUploadState());                       // all updates to UI widgets need to be done on the UI thread
            }
        });`
```

Now, although the ping call is giving me a successful response, the upload part is giving me an error.

> E/Activity file: failed to upload file.
>                    com.kinvey.java.KinveyException: 
>                    REASON: No user is currently logged in.

I've searched a lot on this topic, on kinvey's discussion platform and here too. But I'm still stuck. I don't know where I'm going wrong or what I might be missing.

If anyone is out there who has successfully managed to upload images through kinvey then please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of Kinvey operations must be provided via a logged user.
You must sign up (or login) before you start to i/o any information.

```java
mKinveyClient.user().create("username", "password", new KinveyUserCallback()) {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        CharSequence text = "Could not sign up.";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(User u) {
        //here we go on uploading file
    }
});
```

You can find more info about users [here](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/users)

Answer (score 0):

Sharmistha,

Yes, every app action needs an active user context.
So you will need to login in the app and then upload the file.

Please take a look at the following:
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/users#ActiveUser
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/files#Uploading

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey